# Calling an executable generate during make in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a code needs complicated parameter input. So my design is to write a compiler that compiles a simpler input to C++ code and then compile the C++ code into the big project. Now the problem is the compiler itself is written in C/BISON and I need to compile it before generating C++ code. Since both part of the code is made using CMake, is it possible to let CMake have a 2-steps compile, i.e. compile the compiler, and call the compiler to generate C++ code, and then compile the generated C++ code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can do something like this:

```
add_executable(compiler compiler.c)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT complicated.cpp COMMAND compiler DEPENDS compiler.c)
add_executable(main_program complicated.cpp)
```

This builds your `compiler` from `compiler.c`, then adds a custom command that uses the `compiler` to generate `complicated.cpp`. Finally, the `main_program` is built from the generated code.

`add_custom_command` has some [more optional parameters](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_command), e.g. to supply command line arguments to `compiler`. Adding the compiler source files as dependencies of the custom command (i.e. `DEPENDS compiler.c`) is needed if you want `complicated.cpp`to be re-generated when you make changes to the compiler.